# Combining SQL queries with shared logic

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm currently duplicating a rather large SQL aggregation query so that I can run it once to return the metrics for the entire data set, then again to group the metrics for each day.

Here's a simplified example of the query that calculates the overall metrics.

```
SELECT
  sum(sentiment) FILTER (WHERE user = :user) AS total_sentiment,
  avg(sentiment) FILTER (WHERE user = :user) AS average_sentiment,
  count(messages) FILTER (WHERE sender = :user) AS total_messages
FROM
  "Messages"
WHERE
  date >= :start AND date < :end;
```

And here's the one that calculates the same metrics, but once for each day.

```
SELECT
  date_trunc('day', date) AS date,
  sum(sentiment) FILTER (WHERE user = :user) AS total_sentiment,
  avg(sentiment) FILTER (WHERE user = :user) AS average_sentiment,
  count(messages) FILTER (WHERE sender = :user) AS total_messages
FROM
  "Messages"
WHERE
  date >= :start AND date < :end;
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

Is there a way to combine these two queries without having to duplicate most of the logic?

Building the query strings programmatically is an option, but I'd definitely rather not go down that path.

If the queries were actually as simple as the examples above, duplicating them wouldn't be as much of an issue, but they deal with more complex joins and statistical functions—keeping them in sync is already tricky.

Ideally, the output would be a table whose first row contained the overall metrics and the rest of the rows would be the per-day calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest method would be to use `grouping sets`:

```
SELECT date_trunc('day', date) AS date,
       sum(sentiment) FILTER (WHERE user = :user) AS total_sentiment,
       avg(sentiment) FILTER (WHERE user = :user) AS average_sentiment,
       count(messages) FILTER (WHERE sender = :user) AS total_messages
FROM "Messages"
WHERE date >= :start AND date < :end
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( (), (date) );
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use windowed functions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  date_trunc('day', date) AS date,
  sum(sentiment) FILTER (WHERE user = :user) OVER() AS total_sentiment,
  avg(sentiment) FILTER (WHERE user = :user) OVER() AS average_sentiment,
  count(messages) FILTER (WHERE sender = :user) OVER() AS total_messages,
  sum(sentiment) FILTER (WHERE user = :user) OVER(PARTITION BY date_trunc('day', date)) 
     AS total_sentiment_per_day,
  ...
FROM "Messages"
WHERE  date >= :start AND date < :end;
ORDER BY 1
```